# Android - Unexpected layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, imagebutton

i haven't many experience in android development. this is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.categoriaA1:
        myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata1);

    case R.id.categoriaA2:
        myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata2);
    case R.id.categoriaA3:
        myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata3);
    case R.id.categoriaA4:
        myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata4);
    }
```

myAvatar is an ImageView.
when i click in one of the four imageButton , the result is always the same: Case R.id.categoriaA4. 
Why??

Comment: add break for each statements..

Comment: `experience in android development` - I'd say `switch/case` is in almost every language, so I'd suggest going thru some tutorials on Java basics first.

Comment: Many languages do not use `break;`.  For example, Visual Basic where many learning Java developers come from.

Comment: thank you simon for your understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `break` to each **case**. like

```
  switch(v.getId()){

case R.id.categoriaA1:
    myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata1);
    break;

case R.id.categoriaA2:
    myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata2);
    break;
case R.id.categoriaA3:
    myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata3);
    break;
case R.id.categoriaA4:
    myAvatar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cata4);
    break;
}
```